# Unable to install SQL Server Express 2014 Management Studio

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, sql-server, windows-installation, sql-server-express

Unable to install SQL Server Express 2014 Management Studio on Windows 7/8.1
SQL Server 2012 is already installed on PC.

Error is **Same architecture installation - Failed**

No results in [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=SQL+Server+Express+2014+Management+Studio+installation+error+Same+architecture).

**Detailed error info**:
BlockMixedArchitectureInstall   Checks whether the installing feature(s) are the same CPU architecture as the specified instance.   Failed  The CPU architecture of installing feature(s) is different than the instance specified. To continue, add features to this instance with the same architecture.

Comment: Check your bit-levels. The SQL Mgmt Studio should be the same bit-level as the SQL instance on the machine (32 or 64-bit).

Answer (score -1):

[Solved](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting129.htm)

During installation select "Perform New installation" type.

Comment: How quote the relevant information, like the error, then provide the solution.  Just providing a link to a third-party website and a single comment isn't that helpful.